# JPA. How to do a join with legacy table

Tags: jpa

I have the following Entity class

```
public class ReportRequest {

@Id
@GeneratedValue (strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;
private String requestorUsername;
    ...
}
```

which maps to a table, ReportRequest, and say I have a legacy table, User, with the following fields `(id, username, fullname)`, where requestorUsername in the ReportRequest table maps to username in User table.

What's the best way to retrieve a `ReportRequest` object with the requestor's full name?  Would I have to create a User entity object? How would I do it with JPQL, native SQL?

Comment: Not completely sure I understand you here. What is ReportRequest mapped to now? A different table? What is in your example requestorUsername? Is that mapped to the username field in you legacy table?

Comment: ReportRequest maps to a ReportRequest table and it has a requetorUsername field.  This field can use to join with a legacy table, User.

Comment: Yes, you would map the user table to a User entity, and create a ManyToOne or OneToOne association between the entities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As JB Nizet suggested, I just mapped the table to an entity, MyUser.  Note that you can also map an Entity to a database view instead of table.

```
public class ReportRequest {

@Id
@GeneratedValue (strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;

@OneToOne(targetEntity=MyUser.class)
@JoinColumn(name="requestor")
private MyUser requestor;  
   ...
}
```

And the entity class will look like

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user", catalog="somecatelog", schema="myschema")
public class MyUser {

@Id
@Column(name="USERID")
private String userId;

    //don't want to modify data
@Column(name="FIRST_NAME", insertable=false, updatable=false)
private String firstName;

@Column(name="LAST_NAME", insertable=false, updatable=false)
private String lastName;

}
```